# How to initialize an array of custom structs in Assembly

Tags: assembly, struct, masm, irvine32, masm32

I'm working on an assembly language project where I need to define a custom struct `COORD` which defines a 3-D coordinate and then define an array of `COORD` objects

Here is my code so far:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

COORD STRUCT
    X    WORD ?
    Y    WORD ?
    Z    WORD ?
COORD ENDS

.data
coordinates COORD <1, 2, 3>, <5, 10, 15>, <6, 12, 18>, <7, 14, 21>, <8, 16, 24>
```

When I try to build the project I get these errors:

```
 error A2163: non-benign structure redefinition: incorrect initializers : COORD
 error A2164: non-benign structure redefinition: too few initializers : COORD
 error A2164: non-benign structure redefinition: too few initializers : COORD
 error A2036: too many initial values for structure
```

So how do I go about properly defining a `COORD` struct that represents a 3-D coordinate and defining an array of `COORD` structs. If someone could please explain how to do this any why these errors are happening it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried defining just one?

Comment: Is it possible that something else you are including directly or indirectly has defined `COORD` already? Try a different name as an experiment.

Comment: Yes, `Irvine32.inc` includes `SmallWin.inc` which already contains an incompatible definition of `COORD`.

Comment: @Jester thank you for pointing that out I'll update my code and see if the issue persists

Comment: @JonGrimes20 did you check if it worked after renaming the Struct? If it did, adding an answer could help future readers of the post